# OpenStack failed to find allocation candidate when resources are abundant

Tags: openstack

I am deploying OpenStack (release Victoria) on lab servers following the official installation guide: https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/index.html

I have completed all prior steps before “Launch an instance”, and the verification step of each installation stage works as expected.

However, when I tried to launch an instance on the provider network following the guide, it failed. The VM instance is in error state.

```
openstack server list

+--------------------------------------+-------------------+--------+----------+--------+---------+
| ID                                   | Name              | Status | Networks | Image  | Flavor  |
+--------------------------------------+-------------------+--------+----------+--------+---------+
| 58ab0d88-f06a-44da-862a-5db52874437f | provider-instance | ERROR  |          | cirros | m1.nano |
+--------------------------------------+-------------------+--------+----------+--------+---------+
```

I tried to track down the error through the log. Here is some relevant information:

In nova-scheduler.log:

```
INFO nova.scheduler.manager [req-0431dbe2-ab1f-4521-937b-138ee7b8f047 c0a9aa1030954b949091485729d00849 2b4ad03e0ef44224a2485d5a693fa347 - default default] Got no allocation candidates from the Placement API. This could be due to insufficient resources or a temporary occurrence as compute nodes start up.
```

In nova-conductor.log:

```
ERROR nova.conductor.manager [req-0431dbe2-ab1f-4521-937b-138ee7b8f047 c0a9aa1030954b949091485729d00849 2b4ad03e0ef44224a2485d5a693fa347 - default default] Failed to schedule instances: nova.exception_Remote.NoValidHost_Remote: No valid host was found.
```

In placement.log:

```
INFO placement.requestlog [req-a07ff6d3-c224-4049-b6d7-da8d99b8f2d6 7a173b73de394296a25cb65adbcb98c7 ac8373bed81b412f875ba310dac066d3 - default default] 10.196.40.110 "GET /allocation_candidates?limit=1000&resources=DISK_GB%3A1%2CMEMORY_MB%3A64%2CVCPU%3A1&root_required=%21COMPUTE_STATUS_DISABLED" status: 200 len: 53 microversion: 1.35
```

It seems that OpenStack failed to place the new VM instance. I also check to make sure the compute node is up and running:

```
openstack hypervisor list

+----+----------------------------------+-----------------+-------------+-------+
| ID | Hypervisor Hostname              | Hypervisor Type | Host IP     | State |
+----+----------------------------------+-----------------+-------------+-------+
|  1 | my.server.resolved.name.here     | QEMU            | 10.196.44.1 | up    |
+----+----------------------------------+-----------------+-------------+-------+
```

```
openstack hypervisor show my.server.resolved.name.here

+------------+-----------+
|   Field    |   Value   |
+------------+-----------+
|    ...     |    ...    |
+------------+-----------+
|   vcpus    |    104    |
+------------+-----------+
| vcpus_used |     0     |
+------------+-----------+
```

But if I test the placement, it does not work even with 1 vCPU.

```
openstack allocation candidate list --resource VCPU=1

# Empty result here.
```

Is there any way to further narrow down the problem? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Update:

```
sudo nova-manage cell_v2 list_hosts

+-----------+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| Cell Name |              Cell UUID               |             Hostname             |
+-----------+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
|   cell1   | 3132ca83-61ad-4a49-9aac-3d8863255d0a | my.server.resolved.name.here     |
+-----------+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: What does `nova-manage cell_v2 list_hosts` show? It can take up to `discover_hosts_in_cells_interval` (nova.conf) seconds until the scheduler discovers new compute nodes.

Comment: @eblock I updated the output above.

Comment: Could the placement api be configured incorrectly? I assume you already tried restarting some of the services like apache (placement)? Maybe turn on debug logs to see if it reveals anything new.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute:

```
openstack hypervisor show 1 -f shell | grep -E 'memory_mb|vcpus|free'
```

and probably you don't have enough resources to spawn that instance.

You can try to change the nova `weights` parameters in nova.conf.